# Mongoose middleware post - `update` not working

Tags: mongoose

I'm using mongoose 4.11.3. I'm trying to use post `update` middleware. It's not working. I tried the `save` one it's working fine. Not sure what's wrong.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const ProfileSchema = Schema({
  // schema defined here
})

// working fine
ProfileSchema.post('save', function () {
    console.log('save called') 
})

// not working
ProfileSchema.post('update', function (err, doc, next) {
    console.log('update called') 
})
```

I'm calling `findOneAndUpdate`, the data is getting updated but update middleware is not getting called. Even pre is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me but not sure why `'update'` is not working.

```
ProfileSchema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function () {
    console.log('pre - update')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The "update" hook will not be called if you use

```
Profile.updateOne();
Profile.findOneAndUpdate();
```

and so on.

The reason why "`findOneAndUpdate`" is working because you are using

```
Profile.findOneAndUpdate();
```

Should make sense.